# Extending a custom resumable download class

Tags: c#

I have an event handler named DownloadProgressChanged in my Download class. It takes four arguments through DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs class, which are BytesReceived, TotalBytesToReceive, ProgressPercentage & CurrentSpeed.

I'm able to download and resume files. Stop them too. Now adding the data needeed by the the DownloadProgressEventArgs is making me confused. The main problem is I don't know where the info needed by the BytesReceived argument is. Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
public class Download
{
    public event EventHandler<DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs> DownloadProgressChanged;
    public event EventHandler DownloadCompleted;

    public bool stop = true; // by default stop is true
    // add option to get current downloaded size
    // add option get current download speed

    public void DownloadFile(string DownloadLink, string Path)
    {
        stop = false; // always set this bool to false, everytime this method is called

        long ExistingLength = 0;
        FileStream saveFileStream;

        if (File.Exists(Path))
        {
            FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(Path);
            ExistingLength = fileInfo.Length;
        }

        if (ExistingLength > 0)
            saveFileStream = new FileStream(Path, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite);
        else
            saveFileStream = new FileStream(Path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite);


        var request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(DownloadLink);
        request.AddRange((int)ExistingLength);
        try
        {
            using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                long FileSize = ExistingLength + response.ContentLength; //response.ContentLength gives me the size that is remaining to be downloaded
                using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    byte[] downBuffer = new byte[1024 * 1000];
                    int byteSize;
                    var sw = new Stopwatch();
                    while ((byteSize = stream.Read(downBuffer, 0, downBuffer.Length)) > 0)
                    {
                        saveFileStream.Write(downBuffer, 0, byteSize);

                        var args = new DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs();
                        //args.BytesReceived = ;
                        args.TotalBytesToReceive = FileSize;
                        args.ProgressPercentage = (byteSize / (int)FileSize) * 100;
                        //args.CurrentSpeed = ;
                        OnDownloadProgressChanged(args);

                        if (stop == true) break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Path);
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(e.Message, filename);
            saveFileStream.Dispose(); //dispose filestream
            return; //not needed because this is the last line of the method, but let's keep it here
        }
    }

    public void StopDownload()
    {
        stop = true;
    }

    protected virtual void OnDownloadProgressChanged(DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        EventHandler<DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs> handler = DownloadProgressChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnDownloadCompleted(EventArgs e)
    {
        EventHandler handler = DownloadCompleted;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }
}

public class DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public long BytesReceived { get; set; }
    public long TotalBytesToReceive { get; set; }
    public int ProgressPercentage { get; set; }
    public double CurrentSpeed { get; set; }
}
```

Also byteSize doesn't change at all. It just stays the same throughout, for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the awesome bug-free working resumable download class with quite a few improvements:

```
public class Download
{
    public event EventHandler<DownloadStatusChangedEventArgs> DownloadStatusChanged;
    public event EventHandler<DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs> DownloadProgressChanged;
    public event EventHandler DownloadCompleted;

    public bool stop = true; // by default stop is true

    public void DownloadFile(string DownloadLink, string Path)
    {
        stop = false; // always set this bool to false, everytime this method is called

        long ExistingLength = 0;
        FileStream saveFileStream;

        if (File.Exists(Path))
        {
            FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(Path);
            ExistingLength = fileInfo.Length;
        }

        if (ExistingLength > 0)
            saveFileStream = new FileStream(Path, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite);
        else
            saveFileStream = new FileStream(Path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite);

        var request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(DownloadLink);
        request.Proxy = null;
        request.AddRange(ExistingLength);

        try
        {
            using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                long FileSize = ExistingLength + response.ContentLength; //response.ContentLength gives me the size that is remaining to be downloaded
                bool downloadResumable; // need it for sending empty progress

                if ((int)response.StatusCode == 206)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Resumable");
                    var downloadStatusArgs = new DownloadStatusChangedEventArgs();
                    downloadResumable = true;
                    downloadStatusArgs.ResumeSupported = downloadResumable;
                    OnDownloadStatusChanged(downloadStatusArgs);
                }
                else // sometimes a server that supports partial content will lose its ability to send partial content(weird behavior) and thus the download will lose its resumability
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Resume Not Supported");
                    ExistingLength = 0;
                    var downloadStatusArgs = new DownloadStatusChangedEventArgs();
                    downloadResumable = false;
                    downloadStatusArgs.ResumeSupported = downloadResumable;
                    OnDownloadStatusChanged(downloadStatusArgs);
                    // restart downloading the file from the beginning because it isn't resumable
                    // if this isn't done, the method downloads the file from the beginning and starts writing it after the previously half downloaded file, thus increasing the filesize and corrupting the downloaded file
                    saveFileStream.Dispose(); // dispose object to free it for the next operation
                    File.WriteAllText(Path, string.Empty); // clear the contents of the half downloaded file that can't be resumed
                    saveFileStream = saveFileStream = new FileStream(Path, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite); // reopen it for writing
                }

                using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    byte[] downBuffer = new byte[4096];
                    int byteSize = 0;
                    long totalReceived = byteSize + ExistingLength;
                    var sw = new Stopwatch();
                    sw.Start();
                    while ((byteSize = stream.Read(downBuffer, 0, downBuffer.Length)) > 0)
                    {
                        saveFileStream.Write(downBuffer, 0, byteSize);
                        totalReceived += byteSize;

                        var args = new DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs();
                        args.BytesReceived = totalReceived;
                        args.TotalBytesToReceive = FileSize;
                        float currentSpeed = totalReceived / (float)sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
                        args.CurrentSpeed = currentSpeed;
                        if (downloadResumable == true)
                        {
                            args.ProgressPercentage = ((float)totalReceived / (float)FileSize) * 100;
                            long bytesRemainingtoBeReceived = FileSize - totalReceived;
                            args.TimeLeft = (long)(bytesRemainingtoBeReceived / currentSpeed);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //args.ProgressPercentage = Unknown;
                            //args.TimeLeft = Unknown;
                        }
                        OnDownloadProgressChanged(args);

                        if (stop == true) 
                            return;
                    }
                    sw.Stop();
                }
            }
            var completedArgs = new EventArgs();
            OnDownloadCompleted(completedArgs);
            saveFileStream.Dispose();
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Path);
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            saveFileStream.Dispose();
            return; //not needed because this is the last line of the method, but let's keep it here
        }
    }

    public void StopDownload()
    {
        stop = true;
    }

    protected virtual void OnDownloadStatusChanged(DownloadStatusChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        EventHandler<DownloadStatusChangedEventArgs> handler = DownloadStatusChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnDownloadProgressChanged(DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        EventHandler<DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs> handler = DownloadProgressChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnDownloadCompleted(EventArgs e)
    {
        EventHandler handler = DownloadCompleted;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }
}

public class DownloadStatusChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public bool ResumeSupported { get; set; }
}

public class DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public long BytesReceived { get; set; }
    public long TotalBytesToReceive { get; set; }
    public float ProgressPercentage { get; set; }
    public float CurrentSpeed { get; set; } // in bytes
    public long TimeLeft { get; set; } // in seconds
}
```

The CurrentSpeed calculation isn't super accurate because it needs time to become accurate. A better way would be find out how much bandwidth your application is using at a given time. But sadly, that too would fail if you're downloading multiple files at the same time.